# SVG makes white lines in the browser

Tags: svg, polygon, adobe-illustrator

I made a 24x24-pixel logo. It consists of polygons that stand side by side.

I'm showing this in various sizes on my web page in the range of **40 pixels** and **24 pixels**.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="katman_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;" xml:space="preserve">
<polygon points="6,20 4,16 2,20 "/>
<polygon points="4,16 2,12 0,16 "/>
<polygon points="6,12 4,8 2,12 "/>
<polygon points="8,8 6,4 4,8 "/>
<polygon points="10,12 8,8 6,12 "/>
<polygon points="14,12 12,8 10,12 "/>
<polygon points="18,12 16,8 14,12 "/>
<polygon points="22,12 20,8 18,12 "/>
<polygon points="12,16 10,12 8,16 "/>
<polygon points="20,16 18,12 16,16 "/>
<polygon points="4,16 6,20 8,16 "/>
<polygon points="2,12 4,16 6,12 "/>
<polygon points="0,16 2,20 4,16 "/>
<polygon points="4,8 6,12 8,8 "/>
<polygon points="6,4 8,8 10,4 "/>
<polygon points="8,8 10,12 12,8 "/>
<polygon points="16,8 18,12 20,8 "/>
<polygon points="18,12 20,16 22,12 "/>
<polygon points="10,12 12,16 14,12 "/>
<polygon points="8,16 10,20 12,16 "/>
<polygon points="16,16 18,20 20,16 "/>
<polygon points="20,16 22,20 24,16 "/>
<polygon points="10,20 8,16 6,20 "/>
<polygon points="14,20 12,16 10,20 "/>
<polygon points="18,20 16,16 14,20 "/>
<polygon points="22,20 20,16 18,20 "/>
</svg>
```

But white lines form between svg elements...
For example:

[image]

Original svg file: [bz.svg](http://www.onurboz.com/bz.svg)

I can't combine them because in some cases I color each one separately. How can I fix this?

Comment: Sounds like a ronding problem. Perhaps you can add a thin border around every element so it hides it at smaller sizes?

Comment: @Tordek you mean, should I design a larger size and add a stroke pixel? Because when I add stroke in the "24px" disrupts the image.

Comment: Right; you could make it, say, 100 times larger and add a 1px stroke around every element.

Comment: @Tordek thank you so much, I tried x100 higher (240px) from 24px. And i add 1px border (stroke)... Unfortunately there were problems with different sizes such as slippage or overlap. Even a dimmer line in certain sizes comes out. Because i show it "24px" from the original "240px". So, 1px border makes 1/100px ( 0,01px border ) :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shape-rendering` will help in most cases. But it is not guaranteed.  You still might find the odd white pixel.  Plus it has the disadvantage that you lose the anti-aliasing on the outside edges.  Leaving the sloped edges "jaggy".

Another solution, as others have suggested, is to add a thin stroke to your shapes.  The width that that stroke needs to be will depend on the slope of the join line, and the 2D rendering engine that the browser uses.

A third solution is to merge adjacent triangles if they are the same colour.  You can write a little javascript to do the merging.  You probably don't have to worry about the adjacent triangles that have different colours.  If the colours are different enough, the slight white line probably won't be noticeable.

A fourth option is similar.  Instead of merging triangles, look for edges of triangles that later triangles abut against, and give those sides a "bulge". For example by using an extra point halfway along that side, that sticks out a bit.  The idea is that the earlier triangle extends under the later one.

One final solution, I can think of, is to run a filter over the shape to remove the anti-aliasing artifacts.

The ideal filter for this would be a median filter, But unfortunately, SVG/CSS has no median filter.  Michael Mullany created [a very clever hack](https://codepen.io/mullany/pen/dmbvz) that simulates a median filter using a combination of the filter primitives that are available.

```html
<svg version="1.1" id="katman_1" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
  <defs>
    <filter id="median">
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0" result="1" preserveAlpha="true"/>
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" result="2" preserveAlpha="true"/>
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0" result="3" preserveAlpha="true"/>
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0" result="4" preserveAlpha="true"/>
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0" result="5" preserveAlpha="true"/>
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1" result="6" preserveAlpha="true"/>
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" result="7" preserveAlpha="true"/>
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0" result="8" preserveAlpha="true" />
      <feConvolveMatrix in="SourceGraphic" order="3" kernelMatrix="0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0" result="9" preserveAlpha="true" />
      <feBlend in="1" in2="2" mode="lighten" result="a1"/>
      <feBlend in="1" in2="2" mode="darken" result="a2"/>
      <feBlend in="a2" in2="3" mode="lighten" result="a3"/>
      <feBlend in="a2" in2="3" mode="darken" result="a4"/>
      <feBlend in="a4" in2="4" mode="lighten" result="a5"/>
      <feBlend in="a4" in2="4" mode="darken" result="a6"/>
      <feBlend in="a6" in2="5" mode="lighten" result="a7"/>
      <feBlend in="a6" in2="5" mode="darken" result="a8"/>
      <feBlend in="a8" in2="6" mode="lighten" result="a9"/>
      <feBlend in="a8" in2="6" mode="darken" result="a10"/>
      <feBlend in="a10" in2="7" mode="lighten" result="a11"/>
      <feBlend in="a10" in2="7" mode="darken" result="a12"/>
      <feBlend in="a12" in2="8" mode="lighten" result="a13"/>
      <feBlend in="a13" in2="8" mode="darken" result="a14"/>
      <feBlend in="1" in2="2" mode="lighten" result="a15"/>
      <feBlend in="1" in2="2" mode="darken" result="a16"/>    
      <feBlend in="a1" in2="a3" mode="lighten" result="b1"/>
      <feBlend in="a1" in2="a3" mode="darken" result="b2"/>
      <feBlend in="b2" in2="a5" mode="lighten" result="b3"/>
      <feBlend in="b2" in2="a5" mode="darken" result="b4"/>
      <feBlend in="b4" in2="a7" mode="lighten" result="b5"/>
      <feBlend in="b4" in2="a7" mode="darken" result="b6"/>
      <feBlend in="b6" in2="a9" mode="lighten" result="b7"/>
      <feBlend in="b6" in2="a9" mode="darken" result="b8"/>
      <feBlend in="b8" in2="a11" mode="lighten" result="b9"/>
      <feBlend in="b8" in2="a11" mode="darken" result="b10"/>
      <feBlend in="b10" in2="a13" mode="lighten" result="b11"/>
      <feBlend in="b10" in2="a13" mode="darken" result="b12"/>
      <feBlend in="b12" in2="a15" mode="lighten" result="b13"/>
      <feBlend in="b12" in2="a15" mode="darken" result="b14"/>
      <feBlend in="b1" in2="b3" mode="lighten" result="c1"/>
      <feBlend in="b1" in2="b3" mode="darken" result="c2"/>
      <feBlend in="c2" in2="b5" mode="lighten" result="c3"/>
      <feBlend in="c2" in2="b5" mode="darken" result="c4"/>
      <feBlend in="c4" in2="b7" mode="lighten" result="c5"/>
      <feBlend in="c4" in2="b7" mode="darken" result="c6"/>
      <feBlend in="c6" in2="b9" mode="lighten" result="c7"/>
      <feBlend in="c6" in2="b9" mode="darken" result="c8"/>
      <feBlend in="c8" in2="b11" mode="lighten" result="c9"/>
      <feBlend in="c8" in2="b11" mode="darken" result="c10"/>
      <feBlend in="c10" in2="b13" mode="lighten" result="c11"/>
      <feBlend in="c10" in2="b13" mode="darken" result="c12"/>
      <feBlend in="c1" in2="c3" mode="lighten" result="d1"/>
      <feBlend in="d1" in2="c3" mode="darken" result="d2"/>
      <feBlend in="d2" in2="c5" mode="lighten" result="d3"/>
      <feBlend in="d2" in2="c5" mode="darken" result="d4"/>
      <feBlend in="d4" in2="c7" mode="lighten" result="d5"/>
      <feBlend in="d4" in2="c7" mode="darken" result="d6"/>
      <feBlend in="d6" in2="c9" mode="lighten" result="d7"/>
      <feBlend in="d6" in2="c9" mode="darken" result="d8"/>
      <feBlend in="d8" in2="c11" mode="lighten" result="d9"/>
      <feBlend in="d8" in2="c11" mode="darken" result="d10"/>
      <feBlend in="d1" in2="d3" mode="darken" result="e1"/>
      <feBlend in="e1" in2="d5" mode="darken" result="e2"/>
      <feBlend in="e2" in2="d7" mode="darken" result="e3"/>
      <feBlend in="e3" in2="d9" mode="darken" result="e4"/>
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g filter="url(#median)">
    <polygon points="6,20 4,16 2,20 "/>
    <polygon points="4,16 2,12 0,16 "/>
    <polygon points="6,12 4,8 2,12 "/>
    <polygon points="8,8 6,4 4,8 "/>
    <polygon points="10,12 8,8 6,12 "/>
    <polygon points="14,12 12,8 10,12 "/>
    <polygon points="18,12 16,8 14,12 "/>
    <polygon points="22,12 20,8 18,12 "/>
    <polygon points="12,16 10,12 8,16 "/>
    <polygon points="20,16 18,12 16,16 "/>
    <polygon points="4,16 6,20 8,16 "/>
    <polygon points="2,12 4,16 6,12 "/>
    <polygon points="0,16 2,20 4,16 "/>
    <polygon points="4,8 6,12 8,8 "/>
    <polygon points="6,4 8,8 10,4 "/>
    <polygon points="8,8 10,12 12,8 "/>
    <polygon points="16,8 18,12 20,8 "/>
    <polygon points="18,12 20,16 22,12 "/>
    <polygon points="10,12 12,16 14,12 "/>
    <polygon points="8,16 10,20 12,16 "/>
    <polygon points="16,16 18,20 20,16 "/>
    <polygon points="20,16 22,20 24,16 "/>
    <polygon points="10,20 8,16 6,20 "/>
    <polygon points="14,20 12,16 10,20 "/>
    <polygon points="18,20 16,16 14,20 "/>
    <polygon points="22,20 20,16 18,20 "/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 3):

[Shape Rendering](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) is your culprit amigo.

Just add `shape-rendering="crispEdges"` to the svg declaration (see in the source example below)...
....or as CSS to hit more than one if you like at the element level like;

```
svg {
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

Enjoy, and cool graphic ;)

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 22.0.1, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="katman_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 24 24" style="enable-background:new 0 0 24 24;" xml:space="preserve" 
shape-rendering="crispEdges"> <!-- **** YOUR NEW FRIEND **** -->
  <polygon points="6,20 4,16 2,20 "/>
  <polygon points="4,16 2,12 0,16 "/>
  <polygon points="6,12 4,8 2,12 "/>
  <polygon points="8,8 6,4 4,8 "/>
  <polygon points="10,12 8,8 6,12 "/>
  <polygon points="14,12 12,8 10,12 "/>
  <polygon points="18,12 16,8 14,12 "/>
  <polygon points="22,12 20,8 18,12 "/>
  <polygon points="12,16 10,12 8,16 "/>
  <polygon points="20,16 18,12 16,16 "/>
  <polygon points="4,16 6,20 8,16 "/>
  <polygon points="2,12 4,16 6,12 "/>
  <polygon points="0,16 2,20 4,16 "/>
  <polygon points="4,8 6,12 8,8 "/>
  <polygon points="6,4 8,8 10,4 "/>
  <polygon points="8,8 10,12 12,8 "/>
  <polygon points="16,8 18,12 20,8 "/>
  <polygon points="18,12 20,16 22,12 "/>
  <polygon points="10,12 12,16 14,12 "/>
  <polygon points="8,16 10,20 12,16 "/>
  <polygon points="16,16 18,20 20,16 "/>
  <polygon points="20,16 22,20 24,16 "/>
  <polygon points="10,20 8,16 6,20 "/>
  <polygon points="14,20 12,16 10,20 "/>
  <polygon points="18,20 16,16 14,20 "/>
  <polygon points="22,20 20,16 18,20 "/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ty :) I tried it. it works I vote well up. But there seems to be a lot of compatibility issues. " https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-crisp-edges " already low pixel quality of the image quality is also disturbing. Maybe there is another solution. Otherwise I'm going to force the merger. Thank you so much.

Comment: @l6ls Another quick hack I use around that sometimes would be to ditch the rendering declaration and fake it with like `svg polygon { stroke: #000; stroke-width: .01; }` except would need considered during your color changes on individual pieces etc.